# Find $t>0$ such that $\text{ball}(x,t)$ belongs to an open interval in the given open cover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed and bounded set. If $S \subset \bigcup_i \text{J}_i$ where each $\text{J}_i$ $(i\in \text{I})$ is a collection of open intervals, show that $\exists$ $t>0$ such that $\text{ball}(x,t) \in J_{i_x}$ for every $x \in S$ and for some $i_x \in \text{I}$

Can there be a proof using only the notions of a limit point (and without using the theorems related to compactness)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists an infinite sequence $(x_k,t_k)_k$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}t_k=0$ and $B(x_k,t_k)\not \in \text{J}_i$ for any $i$.

Since $S$ is bounded, any infinite sequence of points within $S$ must have a limit point and, since $S$ is closed, $S$ contains this limit point.

Let $x$ be a limit point of the sequence $(x_k)_k$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $k$ such that $|x-x_k|\lt \epsilon$ and $t_k<\epsilon$. There is a contradiction here because $x$ must be in one of the $\text{J}_i$ and since $\text{J}_i$ is open $x$ must have a neighbourhood in $\text{J}_i$.

Comment: Does this (proof) make sense : wlog assume $\bigcup J_i$ to be a union of disjoint open intervals. Consider one such interval $(p,q)$ and all the elements of $S$ inside that interval. Denote by $l,m$ the inf and the sup of the elements in the interval. Clearly, $p<l<m<q$. Suppose not. Then if $m>q$, we can clearly have $q$ as the sup, but then $q$ isn't an element of $S$. And again, $q$ cannot be the sup, because it were, then we would have $q$ as the limit point which cannot be true. For similar reasons, $p<l$ and thus all elements of $S$ in the interval lies in $[l,m] \subset (p,q)$

Comment: Now, $t = \frac{1}{2} \min \{|l-p|,|m-q| \}$ for all such $p,l,m,q$ defined in the same way for all intervals. This min exists (we can set the bounds and argue by the completeness axiom)

Comment: What there are infinitely many intervals $\text{J}_i$? You need to prove that there exists a $t>0$ such that $t_i=\frac{1}{2}\min\{|l_i-p_i|,|m_i-q_i|\}>t$ for all $i$.

Comment: set $t_i = \min \{| l_i−p_i|,|m_i−q_i|\}$. Then we can simply choose $t = \text{inf} ~ t_i$ as $t_i ~ \forall ~ i$ is bounded. Also note that the $t$ we chose cannot be $0$, because it were, then the limit point gets out of the open interval, a contradiction. Thus the chosen $t > 0$

Comment: Could you please have a look into this?

Comment: Can you reword your explanation of why $\inf t_i>0$?

Comment: If not, then inf $t_i = 0$ (it cannot be $<0$). When inf is $0$ and we have finitely many $t_i$s then one of $l_i \text{ or } m_i$ is equal to $p_i \text{ or } q_i$. Now if there are infinitely many $t_i$s and $l_i \neq p_i, m_i \neq q_i$ for any $i$, then, re arrange the $t_i$ s.t $a_i = t_j$ where $a_r \leq a_s$ iff $r\leq s$. Now inf $a_i = 0$ $\implies$ the limit point $l_i$ and/or $m_i$ converges to $p_i$ (or $q_i$ respectively) which isn't possible.

Comment: Is that justified?

Comment: Yes. That's ok.

Comment: At one place I claim that all elements will lie inside $[l,m] \subset (p,q)$. That is incorrect and can be fixed easily. Consider the intervals $(m,q)$ and $(p,l)$. If there are finitely many elements in the interval, we can easily create a closed interval that contains all the elements. In case there are infinitely many elements, say in $(m,q)$, then by BolzanoWeistrass, we have a subseq that converges somewhere in $[m,q]$. Now it cannot converge anywhere in $(m,q]$ (due to sup being $m$), so it converges at $m$.  The rest (to show the upper bound < q) is obvious (& I've reached the char lim)